# Receiving attempted import error for typography file

Tags: reactjs

I recently created this H8.jsx file for typography. I'm receiving an attempted import error:

Attempted import error: 'H8' is not exported from '../../../library/atoms'.

The file paths are:
`clients/odyssey/src/library/atoms/H8.jsx` and `clients/odyssey/src/components/organisms/pages/HowItWorksPage.jsx`

If change the H8 to H7, which is an existing file, then it works fine

HowItWorksPage.jsx

```
import { H8 } from '../../../library/atoms';

const HowItWorksPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <H8>Increase Brand Awareness</H8>
    </>
  );
};

export default HowItWorksPage;
```

H8.jsx

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const H8 = styled.div`
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.18px;
  font-family: var(--font);
`;
```

Comment: Can you share your `'../../../library/atoms'` file so we can see how it's imported/exported?

Answer (score 0):

It can't be exported/imported because H8 inside here is expecting a class, but you returned a style object.

```
const HowItWorksPage=()=>{

return (
    <>
      <H8>Increase Brand Awareness</H8>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your component paths I am assuming you simply didn't import `H8` into your `atoms` index for export out to your project.

Given file path: `library/atoms/H8.jsx`

And error: `Attempted import error: 'H8' is not exported from '../library/atoms'.`

Options in `library/atoms/index.js`

- ```
  export * from './H8';
  ```
- ```
  import { H8 } from './H8';
  ...
  export {
    // ... other exports
    H8,
    // ...
  };
  ```